# multiple forks in GitHub's

Tags: git, github

I've tried to make a second fork of the same 3rd party project on github using these instructions:
https://adrianshort.org/create-multiple-forks-of-a-github-repo/
Unfortunately github doesn't allow me to create a pull request to upstream for such "fork" -  there is no such button and upstream's branch in drop down list. It seems it doesn't think that this is a fork at all - the project icon is different.
Apparently changes I did locally with `git remote add upstream` are 
ignored by github server.

Any way to fix that?

What I want is two fully functional (PRs must work) forks of the same project under one github user account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a branch in your existing fork instead of a second fork.

Comment: The problem is that my existing fork contains a lot of changes which  are experimental and can't be merged into upstream yet. And I need to contribute a small change to upstream that also got some improvements from the moment I forked it. So using branch approach I would need to create a branch, rallback all changes I made after forking, pull all changes from upstream to get branch up to date and only then adding the change I want contribute.

Comment: Yes, this sounds good! Note that you made the basic mistake after the fork: You didn't created a branch, you worked in `master`. I would never work in `master` on a fork. Instead I would frequently pull changes from original master into my master and work in a branch. However, nothing is lost, you can correct things.

Comment: @truf, you can create a branch from any point, not just the head of your main branch. If your upstream remote is called upstream and you're working off their master branch, then `git branch upstream/master my-new-fixes` should do what you want.