# Can I fork a git(hub) repo more than once (to the same github account)?

Tags: git, github

Here's the background:
Github repo X was forked to repo K some time ago by. Changes were made to repo K's branch "master," but no pull request was (or will be) issued.
This is the point at which I enter the story. I forked repo K to repo N, created a new branch from "master" and committed some changes, also with no intent to issue a pull request.

Here's the problem:
I still need repo N, but now I also need to work with a new branch on repo X, which isn't contained in the old repo K fork. But github won't allow me to fork repo X. When I try, using the github web interface, it just takes me to my old repo N.
How can I keep my current repo N, and create a new fork from repo X? I have no control over repos X or K.

In other words:
I have this: X → K → N
I want to add this: X → N<sub>1</sub>

Is this a limitation of git, or just of github's interface? If the latter, can I use git command line tools to accomplish the task, including ending up with a new repo on github with repo X as its upstream?

Comment: In short, it's GitHub, not Git. (Git doesn't have the concept of "fork", just raw clones.)

Comment: A workaround is to create a new empty repository of your own and then push N to the new one. `git clone --mirror <url_to_N> && cd <path_to_N> && git push --mirror <url_to_new>`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [multiple forks in GitHub's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29704014/multiple-forks-in-githubs)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+second+fork

Comment: @phd - no, that question is about a problem that occurred after creating the second fork. But does imply that it can be done. Unfortunately, the link in that article that might have explained how is dead.

Comment: @ElpieKay - That would seem to create a second instance of N. Is the idea then to experiment with the copy to avoid risking the original? Or - since I've cloned X to a local repository, could I push that to a new, empty github repo? And then set the upstream of that repo to X?

Comment: @ElpieKay - I took inspiration from your idea and ended up with something I can use. I created an empty GitHub repo, cloned repo X to a local repo, then changed the local repo's origin to my empty GitHub repo and pushed it to get my N-prime. I'm pretty sure that N-prime is now unrelated to X, but at least I have something to work with. Is it possible to set the origin on a GitHub repo (not its local clone)?

Comment: @Scioomnemalumhoc I'm not familiar with Github. As I know, a real forked repo has some internal connection with the original one so that a PR can be done through Github web interface. Without regard to Github, we can connect two arbitrary repositories directly, by in one adding a remote referring to the other, or indirectly, by using an intermedia repository. I don't think we can set the origin on a Github repo. But in the local clone we can set 2 remotes which refer to 2 repositories.

Answer (score 1):

From the command line, you can add X as a remote of your N clone. You can then pull the upstream refs, including the branch in X that you would like, work on these, and push everything back to N later. This can all be done with `git remote ...` and `git fetch ...`. HTH.

Comment: So that would give me both branches on the same repository, which is fine. I'm a bit leery of tinkering with the existing repo, though, since it would be unpleasant to lose the current modifications to the "master" branch. 
But it sounds like the right approach.

Comment: Mm. Sounds a bit messy. Perhaps disable push to the original repo, X as a protective measure.